# Passing textarea input from html to flask

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

1. I am trying to pass textarea input from my html form to flask, but some how i am not able to achieve it. Below is the code.

```
html file
<form action="{{ url_for('next') }}" method="post">
<textarea rows="10" name="test"></textarea>
<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

so i wish to take multiline input from user and store it in the same way for example:

```
user input in textarea:-

abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

the desired output or store it in same way as multiline string and newline.

```
output:-
abc
def
ghi
jkl
```

python code -

```
def next():
  if request.method == 'POST':
     name= request.form['test']
     #this doesn't work

Error -  raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
```

I am very much new to flask and trying to explore.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please provide snippet of whole `<form>` and also paste error message if you get any

Comment: @Daweo Thanks for the reply, I have edited the question and error -  i am just tryimh to figure out how can i pass the textarea multiline input to flask just tried request.form but it is not working and its not the correct way to do it i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is

```
<form action="{{ url_for('next') }}" method="post">
<textarea rows="10" name="test"></textarea>
<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

that is textarea is named `test`, but here

```
def next():
  if request.method == 'POST':
     name= request.form['name']
```

you are asking about something naming `name` which is not present and therefore `BadRequestKeyError` happen, you should do

```
def next():
  if request.method == 'POST':
     name= request.form["test"]
```

Comment: I have use test in my code but giving same error.

Comment: @rajkundra please replace `name = request.form["test"]` using `print(request.form)` and write what did you get

Comment: after passing input in textarea as specified above in my question. it give ImmutableMultiDict([])